# Postgresql Deleting Records Matching Primary Key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, etl

We are getting data via a batch process from a third-party data provider. For the schema they provide, they issue delimited text files indicating records to delete, followed by a different text file of records to add.

My plan for removing the records is to load the records to delete into a temporary table, and then delete records through an inner join. For example:

```
-- main table
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  city VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (city, state));

-- removing records
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE delete_table (
  city VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (city, state));

INSERT INTO main_table (city, state) VALUES
  ('Chicago', 'IL'),
  ('Seattle', 'WA'),
  ('New York', 'NY'),
  ('Springfield', 'IL'),
  ('Springfield', 'MA');

INSERT INTO delete_table (city, state) VALUES
  ('Chicago', 'IL'),
  ('New York', 'NY'),
  ('Springfield', 'MA');

-- Delete statement
DELETE FROM main_table t
  USING delete_table d
  WHERE t.city=d.city AND t.state=d.state;
```

Is this the best way to typically delete records in this case? The record deletions can range from a few rows to a million depending on the table and day and one hundred tables. Additionally, any table with composite primary keys requires a customized where clause. Is there a way to use a natural join, or a USING (column list) predicate instead?

Comment: The query seems adequate (and probably will yield similar execution plan as `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from delete_table d WHERE same condition)` ) But what is you point: avoiding typing in the actual queries?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, there's over 100 tables with varying cardinality of primary keys. I created a simple function to build the where clause conditions based on primary key number, but I want to see if this could be unnecessary. Additionally, I haven't tried to run this logic yet besides a micro-example. I hope to uncover if this is a solid route to proceed before venturing too far down the wrong path as there seems like a number of ways to proceed.